# Check if controller has already been loaded XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have the following code to push a new ViewController in a Split View Controller:

```
Level4ViewController *controller = [[Level4ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModuleViewController" bundle:nil];
    [[detailViewController navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release], controller = nil;
```

The only problem I have, if I were to run this again, a new controller will show, I would like to be able to go to the view that I had before with all my data.

Can anyone help me out here.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Updated code?

```
Level4ViewController *controller;
    for(UIView *view in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[Level4ViewController class]])
        {
            controller = view;
            if(controller == nil)
            {
                controller = [[Level4ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModuleViewController" bundle:nil];
            }
            else {
                controller = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
            }

        }
    }

    [[detailViewController navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release], controller = nil;
```

Comment: Why don't you pop the controller to go back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UINavigationController` has a property `viewControllers` which is a `NSArray` that hold all the stack that has been pushed to the navigation controller, in this array you can check for your view controller if it is there use that one - you check like this -

```
Level4ViewController *lvc;

for(UIView *view in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
     if([view isKindOfClass:[Level4ViewController class]])
     {
          lvc = view;
     }
}
```

and if you already knows that at which index your viewcontroller is there then you can get it from that index as -

```
Level4ViewController *lvc = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

update -

```
Level4ViewController *controller;
for(UIView *view in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
     if([view isKindOfClass:[Level4ViewController class]])
     {
         controller = view;
     }
}

if(controller == nil)
{
    controller = [[Level4ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModuleViewController" bundle:nil];
}

[[detailViewController navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release], controller = nil;
```

Comment: But what is there a statement that can be used, like if(level4Controller is already loaded then push loaded one, else push new one ?

Comment: after getting your view controller instance from that array check if it is equal to nil then use create new instance and push it and it is is not equal to nil then use that one to push.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question above with the code I have implemented, but I know it's wrong, but I don't know where?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a navigation controller

```
FirstScreenViewController *firstScreenVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"1S"];

    if (![self.navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:FirstScreenViewController.class])
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstScreenVC animated:YES];
```